# What is the dual space to $C^1(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence, topological-vector-spaces

Denote the space of continuously differentiable functions by $C^1(\mathbb{R})$, equipped with the $C^1-$norm. My question is what is the dual space to this Banach space? What about $C^k(\mathbb{R})$ for $k\geq2$?

Comment: What norm is there on $C^1(\Bbb R)$ ? I thought $\sup\limits_{x\in\Bbb R}\lvert f(x)\rvert+\sup\limits_{x\in\Bbb R}\lvert f'(x)\rvert$, but it certainly isn't the case.

Comment: Perhaps you mean $C^1([0,1])$?  I haven't seen anything about $C^1(\mathbb{R})$ being a Banach space, or a normed space for that matter.

Comment: As @G.Sassatelli observes, neither $C^o(\mathbb R)$ nor $C^1(\mathbb R)$ are Banach spaces, but Frechet, with the seminorms sup-on-compacts. Or, continuous functions going to $0$ at infinity, or once-continuously-differentiable functions going to $0$ at infinity and derivatives going to zero at infinity are Banach spaces... what is the genuine intent here?

Comment: A somehow related discussion about the case $C^0(X)$ is here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/89274/the-dual-space-of-cx-x-is-noncompact-metric-space